# how does Collections.sort() method sort out an array of "Name" class instance without calling "Name" class's method?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the `Collections.sort()` method. I saw the code below from Java Tutorial Oracle. After `Collections.sort()` method is called within the `NameSort` class, the array of names were sorted according to their first and last name. But I don't see class `Name`'s hashcode(), equals() or compareTo() method been called anywhere. How does the Collections.sort() method actually work underneath? Could someone please explain it to me? Thanks in advance for any help!

Name class

```
public class Name implements Comparable<Name> {
    private final String firstName, lastName;

    public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
        if (firstName == null || lastName == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String firstName() { return firstName; }
    public String lastName()  { return lastName;  }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Name))
            return false;
        Name n = (Name) o;
        return n.firstName.equals(firstName) && n.lastName.equals(lastName);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return 31*firstName.hashCode() + lastName.hashCode();
    }

    public String toString() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    public int compareTo(Name n) {
        int lastCmp = lastName.compareTo(n.lastName);
        return (lastCmp != 0 ? lastCmp : firstName.compareTo(n.firstName));
    }
}
```

NameSort class

```
public class NameSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Name[] nameArray = {
            new Name("John", "Smith"),
            new Name("Karl", "Ng"),
            new Name("Jeff", "Smith"),
            new Name("Tom", "Rich")
        };
        List<Name> names = Arrays.asList(nameArray);
        Collections.sort(names);
        System.out.println(names);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how does Collections.sort() method sort out an array of “Name” class instance without calling “Name” class's method?

It doesn't.  In fact, it calls the `compareTo` method when it needs to compare a pair of `Name` objects.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) for `Collections.sort(List)` says:

> *"Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the [natural ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) of its elements. All elements in the list must implement the `Comparable` interface."*

The `Comparable` interface specifies the `compareTo` method which provides the "natural ordering" that the javadoc refers to.  That's what `Name` implements to support sorting, etcetera.

The other methods (`equals`, `hashCode` and `toString`) are not used for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to notice:

1)Your Name class implements the Comparable interface.

2)It has a compareTo method.

When you pass the arrayList of names to Collections class, it internally iterates over each of the element in the list and compares them with one another by calling this "compareTo()" method.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful comment! Could you please explain it in a bit more detail, like how equals() and hashCode() method has been used to sort out the orders? Or how equal(), hashCode() and compareTo() method work together to accomplish the job? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: If you look closely at the compareTo() method, you will notice equals() and hashCode() method takes no part in the sorting mechanism of your program.
It's actually comparing the objects based on Java Strings compareTo function:
    
      int lastCmp = lastName.compareTo(n.lastName);

Comment: The `equals` and `hashCode` methods of the `Name` class aren't used. The `Name` class relies on the `compareTo` method of the `String` class. Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String- to see what happens when the `compareTo` method of `String` is called

Comment: Thank you very much guys for helping out! Awesome to have people like to helping out beginners like me!

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc for the [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) method already has implementation details, in particular:

> **Implementation Note:**   This implementation defers to the List.sort(Comparator) method using the specified list and a null
>   comparator.

And the Javadoc for [List.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) states:

> **Implementation Note:**
>
> This implementation is a stable, adaptive, iterative mergesort that
>   requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons when the input array is
>   partially sorted, while offering the performance of a traditional
>   mergesort when the input array is randomly ordered. If the input array
>   is nearly sorted, the implementation requires approximately n
>   comparisons. Temporary storage requirements vary from a small constant
>   for nearly sorted input arrays to n/2 object references for randomly
>   ordered input arrays.
>
> The implementation takes equal advantage of ascending and descending
>   order in its input array, and can take advantage of ascending and
>   descending order in different parts of the same input array. It is
>   well-suited to merging two or more sorted arrays: simply concatenate
>   the arrays and sort the resulting array.
>
> The implementation was adapted from Tim Peters's list sort for Python
>   ( TimSort). It uses techniques from Peter McIlroy's "Optimistic
>   Sorting and Information Theoretic Complexity", in Proceedings of the
>   Fourth Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms, pp 467-474,
>   January 1993.

To have a better feel on how your compareTo() etc. methods are used, you can also add a specific `System.out.println(...)` trace statement in each of them, run your program again and look at the output.

If you really need all the details, you will have too look at the [source code for List.sort()](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java)